# How big can a wedge of 2-forms be?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, exterior-algebra

The comass of a 2-form $\alpha$ is the maximal value of $\alpha(u,v)$
for a pair of unit vectors $u,v$.  The symplectic form $\alpha$ on
$\mathbb R^{2n}$ has the property that $|\alpha^{\wedge n}| = n!$.
For example, in $\mathbb R^6$ one has $|\alpha^{\wedge 3}| = 6$.  Are
there 2-forms $a,b,c$ of unit comass on $\mathbb R^6$ such that
$|a\wedge b\wedge c|>6$ ?

Comment: This was posted at MSE a week ago without an answer.

Comment: Isn't the wedge product (with the normalization making $|\alpha^{\wedge n}|=n!$) taken to be $a_1\wedge a_2\wedge a_3=\sum_{\sigma\in S_3}(-1)^{|\sigma|}a_{\sigma(1)}\otimes a_{\sigma(2)}\otimes a_{\sigma(3)}$, so that the triple wedge is just an alternating sum of six terms, made up of the tensor product of unit comass forms? In which case, the inequality $|a\wedge b\wedge c|\leq 6$ should just be the triangle inequality.

Comment: @BenJohnsrude:  The question is about 2-forms, not 1-forms, so the triple wedge is actually a symmetric product, not an alternating one.

Comment: The triple wedge is a sum of $6!/2^3$ terms, not $3!$ terms.

Comment: We can write each $2$-form $\alpha_i$ as $\sum_j v_{ij} \wedge w_{ij}$ with $v_{i1}$, ..., $v_{in}$, $w_{i1}$, ..., $w_{in}$ orthogonal and length at most $1$. Then $\alpha_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_n$ is a sum of $n^n$ wedge products, and the triangle inequality gives $|\alpha_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge \alpha_n| \leq n^n$. This beats $(2n)!/2^n$ from the more naive triangle bound, but it isn't as good as $n!$, which I suspect is the right bound.

Comment: For everyone's convenience, link to the math.SE thread https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713029/how-big-can-a-wedge-of-2-forms-be

Comment: AND [David E Speyer's useful comment on same post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713029/how-big-can-a-wedge-of-2-forms-be#comment9985908_4713029) that can be expanded to an answer.

Comment: @RobertBryant,, it seems to me that in the boundary case of equality in the stable systolic inequality resulting from this question, the closed 2-form has the standard form of a symplectic form with respect to a suitable orthonormal basis.  Is this enough to conclude that the manifold must be Kahler?

Comment: @MikhailKatz:  I think that one way of describing what you are asking is whether, for a symplectic $2n$-manifold $(M^{2n},\omega)$ (i.e. $\mathrm{d}\omega=0$ with $\omega^n$ nowhere vanishing), every `$\omega$-compatible' metric $g$ (i.e., the endomorphism $J$ such that $g(v,w) = \omega(v,Jw)$ satisfies $J^2=-I$), has its associated $J$ be integrable.  The answer to this is *no*  for $n>1$.  (Of course, the answer is *yes* for $n=1$.)

Comment: @RobertBryant, thanks, I had a small doubt because the compatibility condition is usually expressed by an inequality rather than equality.  So then, there are two separate conditions: integrability of $J$ and closedness of the 2-form?  For example, if $J$ is integrable, it does not follow automatically that the contraction with $g$ will give a closed form?

Comment: @MikhailKatz:  Neither condition ($\mathrm{d}\omega=0$ vs. $J$ integrable) implies the other when $n>1$.  The two together are the definition of Kähler.

Answer (score 7):

I think I figured this one out in the end.  It is easy to show that it suffices to prove that for the standard symplectic form $\alpha=e_1\wedge e_2 + e_3\wedge e_4 + e_5\wedge e_6$, one has $|\alpha\wedge b \wedge c|\leq6$ for all 2-forms $b,c$ of comass $1$.  Consider the endomorphism $M_\alpha$ of $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb R^6)$ sending $b$ to $\ast(\alpha\wedge b)$.  Then $\bigwedge^2(\mathbb R^6)$ decomposes into invariant blocks $V+W$ where $V$ is spanned by $e_1\wedge e_2$, $e_3\wedge e_4$, and $e_5\wedge e_6$, whereas $W$ is spanned by the remaining $e_i\wedge e_j$.  The restriction of $M_\alpha$ to $W$ is given by a permutation matrix, whereas the restriction to $V$ is $\begin{pmatrix}0&1&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&0\end{pmatrix}$, with eigenvalues $-1,-1,2$.  Hence the spectral radius of $M$ is $2$.  Finally, by Cauchy-Schwarz $|\alpha\wedge b\wedge c|= |\langle M_\alpha(b),z\rangle|\leq2|b|\,|c|\leq 6 \|b\|^\ast \|c\|^\ast$.  This calculation has apparently eluded researchers in the field for 40 years, and leads to a natural extension of Gromov's optimal (i.e., tight) stable systolic inequality for the complex projective space.

Comment: For the general case, see https://mathoverflow.net/q/448770/613