# How big can a wedge of $n$ 2-forms in $\mathbb{R}^{2n}$ be?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, inequalities, sg.symplectic-geometry, exterior-algebra

$\def\RR{\mathbb{R}}$Let $\omega$ be a $2$-form on $\RR^{2n}$, where $\RR^{2n}$ has the usual Euclidean norm. The **comass** of $\omega$ is defined to be $\max_{|u|, |v| \leq 1} \omega(u,v)$. Here is the main question:

> If $\omega_1$, $\omega_2,\ldots,\omega_n$ are $2$-forms of comass $\leq 1$ on $\RR^{2n}$, what is the maximum possible value of
> $$|\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_n|?$$
> In particular, if $\omega_1 = \omega_2 = \cdots = \omega_n = e_1 \wedge e_2 + e_3 \wedge e_4 + \cdots + e_{2n-1} \wedge e_{2n}$, then
> $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \wedge \cdots \wedge \omega_n = n! (e_1 \wedge \cdots \wedge e_{2n})$, is this $n!$ optimal?

This is a followup to previous posts on [Mathoverflow](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/448599/how-big-can-a-wedge-of-2-forms-be) and [math.SE](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4713029/how-big-can-a-wedge-of-2-forms-be); here are observations from those posts (plus a few more new ones):

1. Define the skew-symmetric matrix $A^k$ by $A^k_{ij} = \omega_k(e_i, e_j)$. Then the comass of $\omega_k$ is the spectral radius (largest norm of an eigenvalue) of $A^k$. Recall that the eigenvalues of a skew symmetric matrix are of the form $\pm \lambda_1 \sqrt{-1}$, $\pm \lambda_2 \sqrt{-1}, \ldots, \pm \lambda_n \sqrt{-1}$, so the condition that the comass is $\leq 1$ is equivalent to $-1 \leq \lambda_1, \lambda_2, \ldots, \lambda_n \leq 1$.
2. In fact, we may assume that, for each $k$, the eigenvalues of $A^k$ are $\pm \sqrt{-1}$, see [David Speyer's comment on the math.SE post](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/9985908). In this case, the condition on $A^k$ is equivalent to saying that $A^k$ is an orthogonal matrix with $(A^k)^2 = - \text{Id}$.
3. $\omega_1 \wedge \omega_2 \cdots \wedge \omega_n$ is multilinear in the coefficients $A^k_{ij}$ of the skew-symmetric matrices. Specifically, it is the unique symmetric multilinear polynomial $P(A^1, A^2, \ldots, A^n)$ in $n$ skew-symmetrix matrices such that $P(A, A, \ldots, A)$ is $n! \operatorname{Pfaffian}(A)$. If $A$ has eigenvalues $\pm \lambda_1 \sqrt{-1}, \ldots, \pm \lambda_n \sqrt{-1}$, then $\operatorname{Pfaffian}(A) = \pm \lambda_1 \lambda_2 \cdots \lambda_n$, so, in the case $A^1 = A^2 = \cdots = A^n$, equality holds exactly when all the eigenvalues are $\pm \sqrt{-1}$.
4. Previous posts have proved the $n!$ bound in the cases $n=2$ and $n=3$. There is also an easy $n^n$ bound; see [David Speyer's comment on the previous MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/posts/comments/1159176).
5. A speculation from David Speyer: If $A$ is a skew symmetric matrix with eigenvalues $\pm \lambda_1 \sqrt{-1}, \ldots, \pm \lambda_n \sqrt{-1}$, then $\sum_{i<j} A_{ij}^2 = \sum \lambda_i^2$. I wonder whether the $n!$ bound might continue to be correct if all that we assume about $A^1, A^2, \ldots, A^n$ is that $\sum_{i<j} (A^k_{ij})^2 \leq n$. (Note that $\sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i^2 \leq n$ implies $\prod \lambda_i \leq 1$ by AM-GM, so the case $A^1 = A^2 = \cdots = A^n$ still works with this weaker hypothesis.) The case of $n=2$ and two distinct two-forms also works.

A related article appeared [here](https://doi.org/10.1007/s00022-023-00685-3).

Comment: Would you mind if I edited this to include the background from the previous questions? While at it, I'd also really like to tweak the notation in two ways: (1) Ask about $n$ two-forms, so as not to suggest an infinite sequence of questions :) and (2) use the notation $\alpha_1$, $\alpha_2$, ..., $\alpha_n$ rather than $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, ... since the alphabetic notation is a pain to engage with. (EG: Imagine writing "let the eigenvalues of $\alpha$ be $(\rho_1, \rho_2, \dots, \rho_{2n})$, the eigenvalues of $\beta$ be $(\sigma_1, \sigma_2, \dots, \sigma_{2n})$ etcetera ...")

Comment: @DavidESpeyer I would much appreciate it, go ahead.

Comment: Okay, edits made. As you can tell, I like this question!

Comment: Thanks a lot!  @DavidESpeyer

Comment: I'll make one more comment. Here is a variant of the problem which doesn't mention skew-symmetry and which might already be known. Let $D(A^1, A^2, \ldots, A^m)$ be the unique symmetric multilinear polynomial in $m$ many $m \times m$ matrices such that $D(A, A, \dots, A) = \det(A)$. Suppose that each $A^k$ has operator norm $\leq 1$. Can we conclude that $|D(A^1, A^2, \ldots, A^m)| \leq 1$?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, Thanks for all your help!  Note that my remark in the original version of the question about a bound for a foursome of 2-forms (which is not as good as $4!$ but much better than existing bounds for the general case) seems to have been lost in the shuffle.

Comment: @DavidESpeyer: Is the $D(A,\ldots,A)$ question only a variant of the 2-form question, or is there an implication between them?

Comment: I haven't been able to find a direct implication. The trouble is that the relationship $\text{Pfaffian}^2 = \text{Det}$ turns into a much messier relationship between $P$ and $D$.

Comment: I will be utterly astonished if there is a larger maximum than the n! as in the question.

Comment: @DanielAsimov: Good, I am convinced.  Can you provide a proof, or else as Herman to provide one one?

Comment: @DavidESpeyer, so is it correct that one can reformulate the problem in a comass-free form as follows?  Let $P(*,*,\ldots,*)$ be the unique symmetric multilinear polynomial which, along the diagonal $(A,\ldots,A)$, specializes to $n!$ times the Pfaffian of $A$.  Now let $A_1,\ldots,A_n$ be antisymmetric matrices of unit spectral radius.  Then the value of $P$ on this $n$-tuple is also at most $n!$.  ??

Comment: Yes, that's correct.

Comment: You mention in your answer to an earlier question that an answer to this leads to "natural extension of Gromov's optimal (i.e., tight) stable systolic inequality for the complex projective space". Any chance you want to elaborate on this a little (say, by editing your question)?

Comment: @DeaneYang, I did.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Yes! Here is a proof.

Define the norm $|\omega|$, for a $p$-form on $\mathbb R^m$, to be the least upper bound of $|\omega(v_1,\dots ,v_p)|$ for vectors $v_i$ of length one. For any $p$ and $q$ we can ask for the smallest number $C$ such that for every $p$-form $\alpha$ and every $q$-form $\beta$ on $\mathbb R^m$ we have $|\alpha\wedge \beta|\le C|\alpha||\beta|$. Call it $C_{p,q}$. It does not depend on $m$, because if $C$ is valid for forms in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ and if $v_1,\dots,v_{p+q}$ span $V\cong \mathbb R^{p+q}$ in $\mathbb R^m$ then
$$
|(\alpha\wedge \beta)(v_1,\dots ,v_{p+q})|\le C|\alpha_V||\beta_V||v_1|\dots |v_{p+q}|\le C|\alpha||\beta||v_1|\dots |v_{p+q}|,$$
where $\alpha_V$ and $\beta_V$ are the restrictions to $V$.

I claim that $C_{2,2n-2}\le n$. This implies that for $2$-forms $\omega_1,\dots ,\omega_n$ we have $|\omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_n|\le n|\omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_{n-1}||\omega_n|$, and therefore by induction on $n$ we have $|\omega_1\wedge \dots \wedge \omega_n|\le n!|\omega_1|\dots |\omega_n|$.

To prove the claim, first observe that $C_{p,q}$ has this other interpretation: it is the smallest $C$ such that the inner product of two $p$-forms on $\mathbb R^{p+q}$ always satisfies $\alpha\cdot \beta\le C|\alpha||\beta|$. This is so because the norm satisfies $|\beta|=|\ast\beta|$  (Hodge star) and $|\alpha\wedge \ast\beta|=|\alpha\cdot\beta|$.

So a restatement of the claim to be proved is that for $2$-forms on $\mathbb R^{2n}$ we have $\alpha\cdot\beta\le n|\alpha||\beta|$. This can be seen by making a change of orthogonal basis so that
$$\alpha = a_1e_1\wedge e_2+\dots a_ne_{2n-1}\wedge e_{2n}$$
for some $a_1,\dots ,a_n$. Write
$$\beta=b_1e_1\wedge e_2+\dots b_ne_{2n-1}\wedge e_{2n}+\dots ,$$
where the other terms will not matter. Then
$$|\alpha|=max|a_i|$$
$$|\beta|\ge max |b_i|$$
$$\alpha\cdot\beta=\sum_i a_ib_i\le n\ max|a_ib_i|\le n|\alpha||\beta|$$.

I did not say why this norm is invariant under Hodge star. Suppose that $\beta$ is a $p$-form in $\mathbb R^{p+q}$. The claim is that $|(\ast \beta)(v_1,\dots,v_q)|\le |\beta||v_1|\dots |v_q|$. Without loss of generality the vectors $v_i$ are orthogonal and of length one. Complete them to an orthonormal basis by vectors $w_1,\dots ,w_p$. Then
$$
|(\ast \beta)(v_1,\dots,v_q)|= |\beta(w_1,\dots ,w_p)|=|\beta|.$$

Comment: Nice answer, this one might go in THE BOOK!

Answer (score 5):

This is an answer to the point/question 5, suggested by David Speyer (as well as a strenghtening of the main inequality, see the **Edit** below). Consider the norm
$$\|\omega\|=\left(\sum_1^n\lambda_j^2\right)^{\frac12}=\sqrt{-{\rm Tr} A^2}.$$
This is a Euclidian norm over the space of skew-symmetric matrices. Then one applies the *van der Korput-Schaake inequality* (actually discovered by Szegö, and probably known to Banach, see the MO [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/q/208025)). It says that if $P$ is a symmetric $N$-linear form over a Euclidian space $X$, and if
$$\forall x\in X,\qquad |P(x,\ldots,x)|\le c\|x\|^N,$$
then
$$\forall x_1,\ldots,x_N\in X,\qquad |P(x_1,\ldots,x_N)|\le c\prod_1^N\|x_k\|.$$
In the present case, we have
$$|\omega\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega|=n!|\lambda_1\cdots\lambda_n|\le c_n\|\omega\|^n,\qquad c_n=n!n^{-n/2}.$$
We deduce therefore
$$|\omega_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega_n|\le n!n^{-n/2}\prod_1^n\|\omega_k\|.$$

**Edit**. As remarked by Mikhail, this can be combined with the obvious inequality
$$\|\omega\|\le n^{1/2}\max_j|\lambda_j|,$$
to recover the main inequality that when the comass of each $\omega_k$ is $\le1$, then
$$|\omega_1\wedge\cdots\wedge\omega_n|\le n!.$$

Comment: Can this be considered a strengthening of the inequality for 2-forms of comass 1, seeing that $\max \lambda_j\geq \frac{\|\omega\|}{\sqrt{n}}$ ?

Comment: @MikhailKatz It seems so.

Answer (score 4):

I was informed by a colleague that there is also a solution to the Pfaffian formulation of the problem, in Lemma 2.1 of the following article:

> *Roos, Bero*, [**On Bobkov’s approximate de Finetti representation via approximation of permanents of complex rectangular matrices**](https://doi.org/10.1090/S0002-9939-2014-12429-4), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 143, No. 4, 1785-1796 (2015). [ZBL1345.28002](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1345.28002).

Comment: You can use "insert citation" button to find well-formatted citation.

Comment: And according to Roos, the proof is due to Hörmander in his paper "On a theorem of Grace", where it appears to be Theorem 4.

Comment: @DeaneYang  In the real case, Roos points out that the proof is due already to Banach.